# How do I set VS2010 project properties in CMake?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, cmake

For example, in my vs2010 project file, I have "Output File Name" (from Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files) to $(IntDir)/%(RelativeDir)/. I know how to do this manually, but for CMake I'm not at all sure.

How do I set such a property, in the CMakeLists.txt file?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `add_executable()` or `add_library()`, the target name is the name of resulting binary, which, i think, will turn into "Output File Name" property during generation.

You can also try to set `OUTPUT_NAME` property for your target.